# Odoo11 install on CentoOS7

Tags: python-3.x, centos, odoo, yum

I just bought new VPS server installed CentOS7 and tried to install [Odoo11](https://www.odoo.com/) on my server.

So I researched some articles and tried following.

```
// Install requirement packages
[root@odoo ~]# yum update -y 
[root@odoo ~]# yum install epel-release -y 
[root@odoo ~]# yum install fontconfig libpng libX11 libXext libXrender xorg-x11-fonts-Type1 xorg-x11-fonts-75dpi wkhtmltopdf yum-utils -y 

// Install PostgreSQL
[root@odoo ~]# yum install postgresql-server -y 
[root@odoo ~]# postgresql-setup initdb
[root@odoo ~]# systemctl enable postgresql
[root@odoo ~]# systemctl start postgresql

// Install Odoo
[root@odoo ~]# yum-config-manager --add-repo=https://nightly.odoo.com/11.0/nightly/rpm/odoo.repo 
[root@odoo ~]# yum install odoo -y
```

After run last command, I get error.

> ...
>
> Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20171110-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-psutil Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20171110-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-requests Error: Package: odoo-11.0.post20171110-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
>              Requires: python3-greenlet
>
> ...

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try this https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/missing-packages-when-installing-v11-on-centos-7-125072

Comment: Thanks, it helped me much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to python3 dependency missing problem though I installed python3 successfully on CentOS.

Finally, I restarted server and it solved the problem. I'm not sure exactly why restart was required.